# Cannot connect to OpenVPN server

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, openvpn, raspbian

I'm trying to run an OpenVPN server on a Raspberry Pi. After installation using apt, I wanted to establish just a raw connection to test it, but I can't connect to the server from another computer. Server has OpenVPN 2.2.1 running on Debian 7.8, client has OpenVPN 2.3.6 running on Windows 8.1. Server side:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo openvpn --dev tun1 --ifconfig 10.9.8.1 10.9.8.2 --port 20004
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 OpenVPN 2.2.1 arm-linux-gnueabihf [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Dec  1 2014
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 ******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 /sbin/ifconfig tun1 10.9.8.1 pointopoint 10.9.8.2 mtu 1500
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Thu Apr 16 19:00:22 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
```

Client side:

```
C:\Users\Adam>openvpn --remote doma.pinkiepie.cz --port 20004 --dev tun1 --ifconfig 10.9.8.2 10.9.8.1
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.6 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Mar 19 2015
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015, LZO 2.08
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 ******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 TAP-WIN32 device [SÃ­Å¥ Ethernet 3] opened: \\.\Global\{C7E73F1C-C5D5-4767-84D9-563C582B9765}.tap
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.9.8.2/255.255.255.252 on interface {C7E73F1C-C5D5-4767-84D9-563C582B9765} [DHCP-serv: 10.9.8.1, lease-time: 31536000]
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Thu Apr 16 18:44:18 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]213.192.60.53:20004
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Well, you only have `--ifconfig` on one side of the connection... other than that, where are you seeing an error saying it didn't work?

Comment: I copied it from wrong terminal. This is the one running right now. When trying to connect using OpenVPN GUI, it says that it is connecting and it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Please try turning up the verbosity level. That should get some output.

Comment: Superficially, it appears that you are using a TAP device on the Windows client. If you're routing then both sides need to use a TUN device.

Comment: +1 for @derobert 's request for more verbosity.. Also I'm presuming you've ruled out any port forwarding or server-side `iptables` problems?